# Java's RandomAccessFIle EOFException

Tags: java, utf-8

Main:

```
package main;

import racreader.RAFReader;

public class RandomAccessFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.err.println("Wrong arguments length");
            System.exit(1); 
        }
        try {
            RAFReader reader = new RAFReader (args[0]);
            try {

                String output = reader.readUTF(Integer.parseInt(args[1])); 
                System.out.print(output); 
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.toString());
            } finally {
                reader.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

RAFReader:

```
package racreader;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

public class RAFReader {

    private final String fileName;
    private final RandomAccessFile reader;

    public RAFReader(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.reader = openFile();

    } 

    private RandomAccessFile openFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
        RandomAccessFile reader = new RandomAccessFile(fileName, "r");
        return reader;
    }

    public String readUTF(int offset) throws IOException {
        reader.seek(offset); 
        String output = reader.readUTF();
        return output;
    }

    public void close() throws IOException {
        reader.close(); 
    }
}
```

The problem is in EOFException in every file (even encoded in UTF8) and every offset. Why?

**UPD:** I try to get my program working with file with this content:

```
Это тест UTF-8 чтения
```

It works fine only if `offset = 0`. Any other offset throws EOFException.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `readUTF()`/`writeUTF()` methods from `RandomAccesFile` use conventions for writing Java `String` objects, which are not necessarily honored by UTF encoded text files. `readUTF()` was not meant to be used for reading arbitrary text file, which was not originally written by using `RandomAccesFile.writeUTF()`.

As method Javadocs specify, `readUTF()` assumes that the first two bytes it reads contain the number of bytes in the following string. This is the case if the string was written to file by the pairing `writeUTF()` method, but in case of the text file this will throw intermittent `EOFException`, since the first two bytes will contain actual characters from the string.

In your case, a different set of classes can solve the problem. Consider rewriting `RAFReader` class using `InputStreamReader`:

```
public String readUTF(int offset) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(fileName);

    Reader fileReader = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    fileReader.skip(offset);

    int charsRead;
    char buf[] = new char[256];

    //Read until there is no more characters to read.
    while ((charsRead = fileReader.read(buf)) > 0) {
        stringBuilder.append(buf, 0, charsRead);
    }

    fileReader.close();

    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

If using `RandomAccesFile` is a must, you can use input stream which wraps the `RandomAccesFile`. The simplest way to do it is through FileChannel, encapsulated by `RandomAccesFile`:

```
InputStream is = Channels.newInputStream(reader.getChannel());
```

Comment: But sometimes I get some special symbols at the beginning of reading with some `RandomAccessFile` offsets. How to self-synchronize UTF `InputStream`?

Comment: If the offset is the number of characters to skip, make sure you are using `Reader#skip()`, not `RandomAccessFile#seek()`. The latter will take position in bytes, so it can point the stream to the middle of the character which is encoded with several bytes, hence the special symbols.

Answer (score 0):

> EOFException - if this file reaches the end before reading all the
>   bytes.

One possible way in which you got EOFException is at line

```
reader.seek(offset); 
String output = reader.readUTF();
```

Maybe the `offset` value is high for file length. Try with `offset = 0` and check if you get `EOF` or not.

Comment: I don't get EOF only if `offset == 0`

Comment: @user23791 Thats your solution. Don't set the file pointer with `seek` function greater than file length.

Comment: But why `offset = 1` throws EOFException? My file contains more than 1 byte

Comment: @user23791 Ask this question in another thread. Maybe someone else can help you.